# Are there any professional Esperanto translators?

Tags: translation, websites

I've looked hard for Esperanto translators. As [this blog article](http://keylingo.com/why-professional-translation-services-rarely-include-esperanto/) discusses, professional translation services rarely if ever include it. The fact that it's this difficult to find someone to help makes me wonder if including Esperanto in the set of languages provided on a Website may be a lost cause. Transifex, the service that I'm using for translation, includes it in the list of languages, but it's starting to look like there just aren't any takers. Can anyone point me to a company or individuals who handle it?

Comment: Go to Youtube and search Evildea and Esperanto Variety Show. Both of them would be willing to do it I bet. Also, Tim Morris is on iTalki. Maybe you could convince him. Finally, there is the website upwork, which has translators. They do have Esperanto translators but I would worry about the quality.

Comment: Esperanto Variety Show is me (Thanks Lumo). I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Prior to starting my studies (currently ongoing) toward becoming a professional translator, I attempted to do some minor translation jobs requiring little or no experience via such websites as [Babelcube](http://www.babelcube.com/) and [Translators Café](https://www.translatorscafe.com/). On the latter website, I signed up as speaker of Dutch, English, and Esperanto, and a few times I got a request for a translation project into Esperanto.

In the end, I didn't get any of them, because one wanted translation into Ido as well (which I don't speak yet), and another presumably wanted someone with more experience, but at least there was apparently some, if not much, demand for Esperanto translators there (and apparently some supply as well, as others must have gotten those jobs I didn't get).

Other than that, most of what I've heard so far is that Esperanto cannot help someone make a living, be it as a translator, an interpreter, or otherwise. I don't know if there are other exceptions out there, but I doubt it is very much.

---

Antaŭ ol mi komencis mian (ankoraŭ ne finitan) studon por iĝi profesia tradukisto, mi provis fari kelkajn malgrandajn tradukaĵojn, kiuj postulis malmulte aŭ neniom da sperto per retejoj kiel [Babelcube](http://www.babelcube.com/) kaj [Translators Café](https://www.translatorscafe.com/). Sur tiu dua retejo, mi registriĝis kiel parolanto de la nederlanda, la angla kaj Esperanto, kaj kelkfoje ricevis peton por tradukprojekto en Esperanton.

Finfine, mi ne estis elektita por tiuj, ĉar unu volis tradukadon ankaŭ en Idon (kiun mi ankoraŭ ne parolas), kaj alia verŝajne volis iun pli spertan, sed ŝajne ja estis almenaŭ iom da postulo pri tradukistoj esperantaj tie (kaj ŝajne iom da provizo, ĉar devas esti, ke aliuloj ekhavis tiujn projektojn, kiujn mi ne ricevis).

Krom tio, plej ofte mi aŭdis ĝisnune, ke Esperanto ne povas helpi iun enspezi monon, aŭ kiel tradukisto, aŭ kiel interpretisto, aŭ alie. Mi ne scias ĉu estas aliaj esceptoj, sed mi dubas, ke estas multaj.

Answer (score 2):

"Esperanto Variety Show" was mentioned in a comment. That's me. I do (and have recently done) translations for a fee. Depending on the project I could help you find some people that I know that are full-time translators who do speak Esperanto, or other experienced Esperanto translators.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick Google Search – could this help: https://www.tomedes.com/esperanto-translation.php

Comment: I had contacted then, but they don't actually do Esperanto. That's pretty common, as it turns out.

Comment: Ok. It’s really strange that they advertise it, then…